# Crying Co-Worker

Tags: united-states, colleagues

I sit next to a co-worker who consistently has issues.  As a human being I feel bad for her, but at the same time I do not appreciate the constant (once a week) loud personal conversations that she has in the office, often times with her ending up with her crying.  This have been going on for close to 2 years now.

These instances usually are not less than 30 minutes, and frequently last over an hour.

Should I suggest she go out of the office for these conversations?  At the moment I am left with putting on headphones and waiting for it to go away.

**As I am a co-worker, not this person's manager, I do not know the best way to proceed without putting myself at risk of being "that guy".**

If there is a way to help them, I would like to do that. In the end the distraction she creates needs to go away, and I am not going to risk my standing in the company.

**UPDATE**:  This is also sensitive due to the fact that I am male and she is a female.  I don't want to be seen as an insensitive jerk.  This is not the same scenario as folks are trying to link to (as a duplicate).

**UPDATE II**: She was given a very nice severance package, so she could figure out her personal issues without worrying about income for a few months. Very nice of the company to do so, and her boss FINALLY observed an incident.

Comment: I think the likely answer is to try and have a conversation and if that fails go to HR. That being said, I don't think there's much we can due to add value to this question and it seems like a pretty common problem. Do let us know if there are specifics which make this problem more difficult to deal with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loud and unprofessional employee](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59451/loud-and-unprofessional-employee)

Comment: Did not think about typing LOUD versus crying!

Comment: From that question... "He is loud speaker, sometimes starts singing and whistling in the office, he talks loudly on the phone. Every small argument with another employee sounds like a fight."

Comment: Is your goal to help your coworker or is it to deal with her crying and not be distracted by it?

Comment: If there is a way to help them, I would like to do that.  In the end the distraction needs to go and I am not going to risk my standing in the company to help her.  ( it sucks honestly )

Comment: @WorkerDrone that may end up being the answer, dang it!

Comment: If you have the same boss I would go  the them.   If you approach this person about loud conversations and tears that is would you are likely to get.

Comment: @Paparazzi  Sadly we do not, and the MGR in question is, well, terrible.

Comment: 1. How can you describe something as "constant" when it happens only once a week? 2. If I read your post right, you are saying that the maximum length of this conversation is a little more than 1 hour. So, it's once a week and for a little more than one hour? Go and have yourself a lunch break!

Comment: If it always happened at lunch time that would be the answer!

Comment: Well, ask her to have her conversations during your lunch time and you're all set.

Comment: Why are people so afraid of just being honest with someone and making themselves 'look bad'?

Comment: I am concerned about my reputation with my colleagues for obvious reasons. @Frammo

Comment: Ask for a different cube.

Comment: Glad to hear things worked out well for the both of you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems appropriate to bring up to this person's supervisor, for the reason of being a significant distraction and affecting your job performance on regular basis. The solution for the individual would be to take their conversation outside the work area, or do after work hours.

However, play by ear: take your best guess at how the supervisor is likely to react. (e.g. is this employee the supervisor's best/favorite subordinate?) So consider the circumstances.

You might also consult with your HR dept to see if there is a policy in place to handle distractions or unprofessional behavior (which this qualifies under) in the workplace.

Comment: A better solution for this individual might be to seek professional help.  If she is audibly crying in the workplace on a regular basis, she clearly has some serious issues to work through.

Comment: @AffableAmbler I agree, for the person crying your advice might make sense. However the person asking the question is not the person crying, but a coworker trying to figure out what HE should do in this situation.

Answer (score 13):

> I do not appreciate the constant ( once a week ) loud personal conversations that she has in the office, often times crying.

A loud conversation (say, 10mins on average) once a week doesn't sound at all like something you should be taking action about. When this happens, go have a coffee break. Problem solved. If the frequency were 3 times a day, I could start to see your dilemma.

Comment: This isn't a frequency thing as much as it is a duration thing.

Comment: Surely someone else would notice them, no?

Comment: @AndrewBerry you would think so, but this employee has not had an on-site supervisor for the last year so this does not help.